# Register Internet-Explorer Address Prefix like: dial://0011123456789

Tags: internet-explorer

**I want to ...**

use individual links that start a program with given parameters using the Internet Explorer.

Normal link:

```
http://www.google.com
```

Adjusted link calling a registered program:

```
dial://0011123456789
```

A popular example for this mechanism is eDonkey.
eDonkey Links look similar to this one:

```
e2dk://mydownload:500232
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to register programs using the Internet Explorer?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the 'Start' button, and select 'Run'. In the resulting dialog box, type "regedit".

Then, go to **[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\URL\Prefixes]**, to view information about the String value "www" with value data as "http://". [or whatever you want.

---

**EDITED:**

**[The Above Location in the registry does not do as mentioned. Please use the utility below instead. My apologies.]**

---

That'll do the trick.

A utility that will do this automatically: http://customurl.codeplex.com/wikipage

Comment: -1: The page you linked to helps you register new URL protocols, but it uses a completely different registry location than the one you mention. (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\URL\Prefixes does not help you register new URL protocols. It helps Windows automatically add the protocol if you type an address without one. For example, if you enter ftp.example.org, Windows will go to ftp:// ftp.example.org/ ) You or someone with editing abilities may consider editing the answer.

Comment: You're right, I tried, and it is as you say, my bad, but the utility does exactly as requested, so, the post is not a complete waste! :) 
Thanks again for indicating my mistake! :)

Answer (score 3):

[Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx)